# Modifying jQuery-Countdown to show also Milliseconds

Tags: jquery, countdown, milliseconds, jquery-countdown

How to modify this [jQuery-Countdown](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/) to show also Milliseconds? I already tried to just set the interval from *1000* to *1*, but it doesn't work.

```
interval = setInterval(moveStep(digits.length - 1), 1);
```

Update: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSBen/ZsPtg/)

Comment: "but it doesn't work" --- was never a good explanation.

Comment: The last digit seems to change every millisecond as it should, but the other digits don't update on time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net - could you reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because 1 milisecond is to little for the code to execute.
People can't see faster than 30 FPS which is 33 miliseconds, so You could just set interval to 33 ms to make it look like it was every milisecond.